# Radius of inscribed circle in the region bounded by 3 tangential circles whose centres form a right-angle triangle.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, quadratics

Since their centres form a right-angled triangle, we can arrange the four circles as shown below:
[image: ![![![enter image description here]
Although there are ready-made formula in this site and in the history such as  [Descartes four circle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem), stating that
$$\left( \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3} + \frac{1}{R_4} \right)^2
= 
2 \left( \frac{1}{R_1^2} + \frac{1}{R_2^2} + \frac{1}{R_3^2} + \frac{1}{R_4^2} \right),
$$
I want to find a new one by elementary method myself.

Using the fact that when two circles touch each other, the distance between their centre is exactly the sum of their radii, we get 3 equations

$$
\begin{array}{l}
x^{2}+y^{2}=(a+r)^{2} \qquad\qquad \,\cdots(1) \\
[x-(b+a)]^{2}+y^{2}=(b+r)^{2} \cdots(2)\\
x^{2}+[y-(c+a)]^{2}=(c+r)^{2} \cdots(3)
\end{array}
$$
where $(x,y)$ is the centre of the inscribed circle.

(1)-(2) yields $$
x^{2}-[x-(b+a)]^{2}=(a+r)^{2}-(b+r)^{2}
$$

$$
x=a+\frac{a-b}{a+b} r \tag*{(4)} 
$$

(1)-(3) yields $$
y^{2}-[y-(c+a)]^{2}=(a+r)^{2}-(c+r)^{2}
$$

$$
y=a+\frac{a-c}{a+c}r \tag*{(5)} 
$$
Putting them into (1) yields $$
\left(a+\frac{a-c}{a+c} r\right)^{2}+\left(a+\frac{a-b}{a+b} r\right)^{2}=(a+r)^{2}
$$
Then the radius $r$ is given as the positive root of the quadratic equation

$$
\left[\left(\frac{a-c}{a+c}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{a-b}{a+b}\right)^{2}-1\right] r^{2}+2 a\left(\frac{a-c}{a+c}+\frac{a-b}{a+b}-1\right)r+a^{2}=0
$$

By the way, we can find the coordinates of the centre by putting $r$ back to (4) and (5).

***Example 1***

If the radii of three given circle are $1, 2$ and $3$, then the quadratic equation becomes $$
-\frac{23}{36} r^{2}-\frac{11}{3} r+1=0 \\
23 r^{2}+132 r-36=0\\ 
r=\frac{6}{23},
$$
and its centre is $\left(\dfrac{21}{23}, \dfrac{20}{23}\right).$

***Example 2***

If the radii of three given circle are $2, 3$ and $10$, then the quadratic equation becomes

$$\left(\frac{1}{25}+\frac{4}{9}-1\right) r^{2}+4\left(-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{8}{12}-1\right) r+4=0$$$$
r=\frac{15}{29}
$$
and its centre is $\left(\dfrac{55}{29}, \dfrac{48}{29}\right)$.

***My Question***

Is there any other method? Your comments and alternative method are highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know there exists a "second formula" for the **centers** ? See formula (2) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3469224/305862) expressed with complex numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting reference using complex numbers.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/985077) gives a formula for the centers in $\mathbb{R}^n$.